# Can I run ROS from a USB Drive?

Tags: rosinstall, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to using Ubuntu and ROS. I have a computer that does not have a lot of storage on it (128 GB SSD), a virtual machine runs a bit too slow to simulate things in gazebo so i want to do a dual boot. However I want to know if there's a way to install ROS and Gazebo to a USB stick so I can make a smaller partition for Ubuntu. Does anyone know if this can be done? Thanks.

-icepaka89

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247342/can-i-run-ros-from-a-usb-drive?/) by [icepaka89](https://answers.ros.org/users/26952/icepaka89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of ROS and gazebo install into `/opt`. While it's possible to mount `/opt` on a different disk, apt (the package manager) and other tools will assume that the disk is available every time you boot your computer, so using a removable drive is likely to cause unusual problems.

It's probably easier to install a second disk if your SSD is getting too small, or install Ubuntu and ROS together on the USB drive, so that everything stays on the same disk. (get a fast USB drive if you can; running your OS from a slow hard drive can really suck)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-06**:
In principle I agree with @ahendrix: doing what the OP suggests is certainly possible in Linux, but if you're just starting out, I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Getting mounting order, permissions and things like `fstab` correct is certainly doable, but will require some research. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-06**:
.. If you do wish to go through with this, search Google for pages that explain how to move the `/opt` directory to a new partition (or how to *mount* `/opt` on another partition). Your USB drive would be the new partition in this case. If you mount *just* `/opt/ros`, you should even be able ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-06**:
.. to get away with not always having the USB drive inserted into your laptop (provided you don't have things like `source /opt/ros/..` in your `.bashrc`, or check for the existence of files before executing commands). If doing this, I'd recommend just putting `/opt/ros` on the external drive.